# Can't build ionic 3 project with new Xcode 10 and mac Mojave

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, ionic-framework

the project was working fine but since I updated the xcode 10 and to mac mojaveOS just problems, for Android works fine. And I already added the flag that I saw on github from cordova [link](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/412) but none of those are making my project run, and if I open the project on xcode it won't even open. Just crash.

```
ionic cordova build ios -- --buildFlag="-UseModernBuildSystem=0"
```

my console log (it stops here on the build)

```
Reading build config file:

Building for iPhone X Simulator

Building project: /Users/quanticosolutions/Desktop/myseg/mobile/platforms/ios/MyApp.xcworkspace

        Configuration: Debug
        Platform: emulator
Adding xcodebuildArg: -UseModernBuildSystem=0

User defaults from command line:
    UseModernBuildSystem = 0

Build settings from command line:
    CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = /Users/quanticosolutions/Desktop/myseg/mobile/platforms/ios/build/emulator
    SDKROOT = iphonesimulator12.1
    SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR = /Users/quanticosolutions/Desktop/myseg/mobile/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch

Build settings from configuration file '/Users/quanticosolutions/Desktop/myseg/mobile/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig':
    CLANG_ALLOW_NON_MODULAR_INCLUDES_IN_FRAMEWORK_MODULES = YES
    CODE_SIGN_ENTITLEMENTS = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Entitlements-$(CONFIGURATION).plist
    CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY = iPhone Developer
    ENABLE_BITCODE = NO
    FRAMEWORK_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/OneSignal/iOS_SDK/OneSignalSDK/Framework"
    GCC_PREPROCESSOR_DEFINITIONS = $(inherited) COCOAPODS=1
    HEADER_SEARCH_PATHS = $(inherited) "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/OneSignal"
    OTHER_CFLAGS = $(inherited) -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public" -isystem "${PODS_ROOT}/Headers/Public/OneSignal"
    OTHER_LDFLAGS = $(inherited) -ObjC -framework "OneSignal" -framework "SystemConfiguration" -framework "UIKit" -framework "UserNotifications"
    PODS_BUILD_DIR = ${BUILD_DIR}
    PODS_CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR = ${PODS_BUILD_DIR}/$(CONFIGURATION)$(EFFECTIVE_PLATFORM_NAME)
    PODS_PODFILE_DIR_PATH = ${SRCROOT}/.
    PODS_ROOT = ${SRCROOT}/Pods
    SWIFT_OBJC_BRIDGING_HEADER = $(PROJECT_DIR)/$(PROJECT_NAME)/Bridging-Header.h
```

my ionic info

```
cli packages: (/usr/local/lib/node_modules)

    @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.19.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.20.0

global packages:

    cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.0.0

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 3.0.0-201710070411
    Cordova Platforms  : android 7.1.1 browser 5.0.3 ios 4.5.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.9.2

System:

    ios-deploy : 2.0.0
    Node       : v8.11.1
    npm        : 5.6.0
    OS         : macOS
    Xcode      : Xcode 10.1 Build version 10B61

Environment Variables:

    ANDROID_HOME : not set

Misc:

    backend : pro
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the first solution i found was to downgrade to xcode 9.4.1 but now i cant run on devices with ios 12, so not the best solution ,with the new vesion had to remove ios platform and added it again, with the latest version of ios and it worked